# Program returning wrong numbers

Tags: c

I am in an intro coding class and I cannot figure out why this program isn't giving me the correct answer and is instead giving me a seemingly random number.

I have tried just putting it as a constant instead of a scanf and it still gives me issues

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MIN_CONST = 7;

int ComputeMinutesLost(int userCigarettes) {
   int minLost;
   int MIN_CONST;

   minLost = userCigarettes * MIN_CONST;

   return minLost;
}
int main(void) {

   int userCigarettes;
   printf("How many cigarettes have you smoked?\n");
   scanf("%d", &userCigarettes);
   printf("You have lost %d minutes to cigarettes. ", ComputeMinutesLost);

   return 0;
}
```

It should just say how many minutes are lost (cigarettes times 7) but it gives a seemingly random number.

Comment: Functions should be *called* to return values. You are not calling it.

Comment: You should always compile with warnings (depending on your setup this may mean checking some boxes in your IDE, writing `-Wall -Wextra` on the command line you use to call the compiler, or something else). Then the compiler can notice that `ComputeMinutesLost` is a function but you are using it like an integer.

Comment: `MIN_CONST` is never assigned a value, but you use it anyway. This is undefined behaviour. Hint: You've shadowed it in the `ComputeMinutesLost` function, another variable with the same name but no value.

Comment: The "Seemingly random number" is the memory address of the `ComputeMinutesLost` function btw, (altough printed with the wrong format specifier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:  The code you posted probably should have flagged you with compile errors, or warnings.  Do you have them turned on?

Change the following:

```
 printf("You have lost %d minutes to cigarettes. ", ComputeMinutesLost);
```

To:

```
 printf("You have lost %d minutes to cigarettes. ", ComputeMinutesLost(userCigarettes));
                                                                       ^------------^  // forgot to include argument
```

By the way, the numeric value you *are* seeing is an integer representation of the address of the function `ComputeMinutesLost`.

Also, (thanks to @unimportant's comment)

in the following code section: //read the comments...

```
const int MIN_CONST = 7;  // one of these...

int ComputeMinutesLost(int userCigarettes) {
   int minLost;
   int MIN_CONST;        // is not necessary, and masks the other
                         // remove one or the other
                         // (as is, this one invokes undefined behavior.)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something simple.

Comment: There's also the declaration of a local uninitialized `int MIN_CONST` in `ComputeMinutesLost`that masks the global `MIN_CONST`.

Comment: @MollieCholette - you are welcome.  (If this answers your question, you can click the hollow checkmark to accept this as answer.)